# Android Emulator - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

When I type in the command

```
    emulator @Andreud
```

where 'Andreud' is the name of the AVD I created, it gives the following errors

```
    PVRDRIInitPVR2D: PVR2D device index (0)Failed to load libGL.so
    error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    Failed to load libGL.so
    error libGL.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and a blank screen in the emulator window, where I should get android home screen, icons, etc shows up.

As per a comment I tried installing ia32-libs

```
    aneesh@nb14:~$ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
    This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
    is only available from another source

    E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

I want the home screen to appear. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On a 64 bit system you need the 32 bit libraries for the Android SDK:

For Ubuntu 13.04 or below:

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

For Ubuntu 13.10 or above:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev:i386
```

The ia32-libs are a 32 bit compatibility package for 64 bit systems, thus only available in such. If you already have a 32 bit installation, you have to install libGL separately:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: I have updated my question to include the error. Is there anything else I must do? I have installed open-jdk-6-jdk and downloaded an android sdk.

Comment: I also installed the android sdk of course

Comment: Edited my answer. Didn't think of the possibility of you having a 32bit system. Sorry ;-)

Comment: I saw that the errors "Failed to load libGL ..." are gone. That's a start! Thank you very much.
However I still get the blank screen/screen with just "android" written. Still only some of the dpad buttons enabled.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark my answer as solution to your problem. This way other users can see that your problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

Type command

```
emulator-arm @Andreud
```

Hope this helps :)