# Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu

Tags: android, software-installation

What all needs to be done to install Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu?

Each of the steps in the answer was found on some different forum as I encountered obstacles getting started with my Android SDK and posted questions in appropriate forums thereafter. So I thought this would be useful in that it is a one stop solution available, in case one ever needs to re-install Ubuntu and install the Android SDK / ADT Bundle from scratch!

Comment: What's a "Android Development Environment"?

Comment: Apparently it's easier for some people to rant than to just answer the question. So, here's the answer;    http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html?m=1 & http://www.webupd8.org/2014/05/install-android-studio-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html?m=1

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**Step 1**

> > Check in System Settings -> Details, whether your Ubuntu is 32-bit or 64-bit

---

**Step 2**

> > (Using software centre or command lines) If your Ubuntu is a 32-bit OS then install `libgl1-mesa-dev`
> >
> > In case of 64-bit OS install `ia32-libs` (Ubuntu 13.04 or earlier), or `libgl1-mesa-dev:i386` (Ubuntu 13.10 and above)

---

**Step 3**

> > Install `openjdk-8-jdk`. If not compatible try `openjdk-7-jdk`, or if still not compatible `openjdk-6-jdk`

---

**Step 4**

> Download the Android SDK command line tools [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download) (they're located at the bottom of the page) and unzip it to a place where you can leave it as long as you need the Android SDK, `/opt/` for instance.

---

**Step 5**

> > Check that the unzipped ADT Bundle folder (or Android SDK folder, as the case may be) have the folders `tools` and `platform-tools`. If `platform-tools` folder is absent, you should be able to install it from the android virtual device manager, which can be run by typing the command
> >
> > ```
> >    android
> > ```
> >
> > in the terminal. These folders contain some important commands stored. Add them to your executable path. Adding them to the path can be done as follows:
> >
> > First execute `gedit ~/.pam_environment`. A file opens. Just add these lines to that file:
> >
> > ```
> >    PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/path/to/tools
> >    PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/path/to/platform-tools
> > ```
> >
> > Here you have to replace `/path/to/tools` and `/path/to/platform-tools` by the absolute paths according to where you unzipped the SDK or the ADT bundle download. Now all the commands `adb`, `android`, `emulator` etc can be simply executed in the terminal without giving absolute paths. That is, you will not get a "command not found" error if you gave it without its absolute path.

---

**Step 6**

> > Type `android` into the terminal and, if **Step 5** was done correctly, the Android SDK Package Tool will start, where you can finish your installation.

Comment: Why would you need to modify GRUB configuration???

Comment: @Aneesh better to put your parameters to `~/.pam_environment` instead of `~/.bashrc`. [Session-wide environment variables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! It saves the execution of export commands at every restart, true?

Comment: Please Note: ~/.pam_environment is not Shell Script and cannot process $PATH, only simple assignments.

Comment: As the `.pam_environment` file is in the home directory, hence owned by the user, why does `... .pam_environment` need to be run with the `sudo` command?

Comment: Good to see my answer edited. Need to keep updating from time to time, as the method could be completely different later on!

Comment: Really, better to add `PATH="$PATH:/path/to/tools:/path/to/platform/tools"` to your `.profile`. `.pam_environment` is overwritten if you change language configuration...

Comment: I found that I had to run ./android (in tools) to have adb (in platform-tools).

Comment: @Host-website-on-iPage Could you tell me why we need libgl1-mesa-dev:i386?

Comment: Because when I ran the emulator command before installing the libgl1-mesa-dev:i386, I got an error saying something like "Failed to load ...". See the question and Andre Stannek's answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/220896/android-emulator-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: ADT bundle doesn't have `tools` or `platform-tools` folders for me...

Comment: Is there a reason you recommend installing OpenSDK 7 and not 8?

Comment: @Rustavore Download the command line tools at the bottom of the download page

Comment: Also: You have to go to `path/android-sdk-linux/tools` and execute `./android` in order to actually install the sdk...

Comment: Good to actually learn from a new version of my own answer! I installed Android SDK from this guide and successfully unlocked the bootloader of my android phone! Kudos to Askubuntu Community!

Comment: simple and sweet... this should be added at android official download page.. great answer +1, and thanks SIR

Answer (score 129):

Actually, I think you should use [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) to develop android application. However, if you have your reason to use eclipse, you can follow the following guide.

```
Target     : Super Newbies
IDE        : Eclipse
Description: Provide a GUI method to install Android IDE using Eclipse
```

### 1. **Installing Java Runtime (JDK) and Eclipse IDE**

- Search `Software` on Ubuntu and launch `Ubuntu Software Center`

  [image: Searching]
- Search `Java` on `Ubuntu Software Center` and then install the `OpenJDK Java Runtime`.

  [image]
- Search `Eclipse` on `Ubuntu Software Center` and then install it.

  [image]
- If you have successfully installed eclipse and JDK, it will appear in the search result on your computer.

  [image] [image]
- For the JDK, you can also press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and type command `java -version` to check again.

  [image]
- Tips : Lock the eclipse icon on launcher.

  [image]

---

### 2. **Downloading SDK**

- Go to http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html to download the latest version of SDK.
  [image]
- Scroll down and click `DOWNLOAD FROM OTHER PLATFORMS`
  [image]
- Click `android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz` under `Linux 32 & 64-bit` of `SDK Tools Only`.

  [image]
- Tick `I have read and agree with the above terms and conditions` and click `Download android-sdk_r22.6.2-linux.tgz`.

  [image]
- Wait for the download process.

  [image]

---

### 3. **Preparing for Installation**

- Go to the location where you set to download the file.
- Rigth click the file[.tgz] and select `Extract Here`.

  [image]
- Now you can see that a file called `android-sdk-linux` appears as if the following.

  [image]
- Enter the folder `android-sdk-linux`.

  [image]
- Enter the folder `tools` and then copy the folder location.

  [image]
- Press the keys <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and then use the following command. Where `/home/casper/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools` is the location I copied previously. You can just type `cd` and right click to past the location to the terminal.

  ```
      cd /home/casper/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/tools
      ./android
  ```

  [image]
- Now the `Android SDK Manager` will be run.

---

### 4. **Installing Packages**

- Click <kbd>Install [Number] packages...</kbd>.

  [image]
- Click `Accept License` and then click <kbd>Install</kbd>.

  [image]
- Wait for the installation process.

  [image]
- Finally, this message will be shown.

  [image]

---

### 5. **Editing ".bashrc"**

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a new terminal and type : `gedit ~/.bashrc`

  [image]
- Now the following text will appear.

  [image]
- Add the following to the **top** of the entire text and then save it. (Do not close the file)

  ```
      export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
      export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
  ```
- Example :

  [image]
- **[Recommended]** Move the whole file `android-sdk-linux` to your eclipse's workspace and under a folder that you create named `Android`. Moreover, you have to copy the location.

  [image]
- Now back to the ".bashrc" file and the replace the '~' with the location you copied previously and then save it and close it.

  [image]
- Logout and relogin your Ubuntu system.

---

### 6. **Setting Up an Android Virtual Device**

- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and type `android avd` to open  the Android Virtual Device Manager.

  [image]

  [image]
- Click <kbd>New...</kbd>. Set up like the following and click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

  [image]
- Click your virtual device and then click <kbd>Start...</kbd>.

  [image]
- Click <kbd>Launch</kbd>.

  [image]
- Launching your virtual device
  [image]

---

### 7. Installing ADT Plugin on Eclipse

- Start Eclipse and go to <kbd>Help</kbd> -> <kbd>Install New Software...</kbd>

  [image]
- Click <kbd>Add...</kbd>.

  [image]
- Type the following and then click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

  ```
   Name     :    ADT Plugin
   Location :    https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
  ```

  [image]
- Tick the checkbox of `Developer Tools` and then click <kbd>Next></kbd>.

  [image]
- Click <kbd>Next></kbd>.

  [image]
- Click "I accept the..." and click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

  [image]
- Wait for the installation process.

  [image]
- Restart eclipse.

  [image]
- Click <kbd>Open Preferences</kbd>.

  [image]
- Copy your own SDK location (The location of the file `android-sdk-linux`).

  [image]
- Paste to the `SDK Location:` textbox and then click <kbd>Apply</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>.

  [image]
- Enjoy to create any android application with your Ubuntu.

  [image]

Comment: Looks like a nice tutorial, however I would personally just install `openjdk-7-jdk`, download the ADT (Eclipse including the SDK from android.com) and create a shortcut in the Dash. This way you also have the latest version of Eclipse.

Comment: I just want to provide the easiest way with screenshots for super newbies to set up the environment. I will try you method and post it below =].

Comment: Would you mind if I put my method in an answer below?

Comment: Good!! Maybe I can help you add some screenshots

Comment: Why do I need to install Eclipse? What if I don't like eclipse? What if I don't have Java installed? Why too many screenshots?

Comment: Because this is just for newbie...Screenshots are important. 
And I will update the post for Java installation. If you don't like eclipse, you can find other posts and no one force you. =]

Comment: I can't copy and paste the commands in the screenshots. The post is heavier (in terms of the amount of data) and will take longer to load. This can be a serious problem for people with slow connections. The post is useless to people using text based browsers or who have disabled the displaying of images. The post is useless for people who have sight problems and are maybe accessing the site using text-to-speech software. Newbies or not is not a reason to overload a post with pointless images. Please, trim it down to the essentially relevant.

Comment: Why you cannot copy the text? ~.~ I have typed all the commands. Anyway, maybe you are right.

Comment: Few tips: using the `Android SDK Manager`, install `Intel x86 Atom System Image` for API 19 (latest, all APIs are backwards compatible so don't use old ones) as well. Then use this one to create an AVD. The default image is **really** slow, it can take 30 minutes to only boot it up and it can use 100% CPU. This is because it is ARM and your system is x86, so it has to emulate everything. Using Intel's image your PC can (probably) make use of your CPU's virtualisation capabilities and it'll boot in less than 10 seconds. Also check `Use Host GPU` to prevent lag in the AVD.

Comment: I really enjoyed this screenshots. Thanks for wonderful work.

Comment: For those of you running 64-bit Ubuntu 14.10, do this `sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6`. That's because you need the supporting 32-bit libraries and `ia32` is no longer available. Source: http://dandar3.blogspot.mx/2014/03/android-sdk-tools-on-ubuntu-1404-beta.html

Comment: a comment just to get a link to this tutorial)

Comment: @CasperLI Android sdk is now available on Ubuntu repo. `sudo apt-get install android-sdk`. Can you make a tutorial based on that?

Comment: Answer is very good but I think you should edit this cause it is outdated

Comment: Hello, I have managed to install the Android SDK thanks to the response of the user @Kin. I only have one question, is it necessary to install eclipse to develop with cordova and Phonegap? If necessary, why is it necessary?

Comment: I think the tutorial is outdated now. i.e. `./android` doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 6):

This may seem to be a long answer, but I tried to explain every step as detailed as possible so nothing can go wrong. You can set this up in less than 5 minutes, even as a beginner.

---

1. You'll need Java to use Eclipse, so install it first:

   *[Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) is an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). The Android ADT package is being bundled with the Eclipse IDE by default. You can also choose to use another IDE (for example [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/)) if you prefer, but because Eclipse is the default I'll cover only Eclipse in this tutorial.*

   1. Open a terminal

      Search for it in your Dash or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

      [image: Terminal]
   2. Execute the following commands:

      ```
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
      ```

      Check if you see any errors on your screen, then continue.
2. Now download the Android ADT bundle (this is Eclipse + the Android SDK):

   1. Click [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) to go to the download page.
   2. Click on `Download the SDK (ADT Bundle for Linux)`
   3. Check `I have read and agree with the above terms and conditions`
   4. Select your architecture:

      [How can I check this?](https://askubuntu.com/a/65731/270074)

      - Check `32-bit` if you've a 32-bit Ubuntu
      - Check `64-bit` if you've a 64-bit Ubuntu
   5. Click on `Download the SDK ADT Bundle for Linux`
3. Install the Android ADT bundle:

   1. Open the `.zip` file you've just downloaded
   2. Extract all files to a directory, for example:

      ```
      ~/ADT
      ```

      After extraction this directory should contain 2 other directories:

      ```
      ~/ADT/eclipse
      ~/ADT/sdk
      ```
4. Add the `platform-tools` binaries to your `$PATH`:

   *This is not neccesary, it'll make commands like `adb` accesible from a terminal.*

   1. Open a terminal
   2. Execute the following command:

      ```
      nano ~/.profile
      ```
   3. Add the following line on top:

      ```
      PATH="$HOME/ADT/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH"
      ```
   4. Save the file

      You can do this by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
5. Create a shortcut in your Dash to easily launch the ADT:

   1. Open a terminal
   2. Execute the following command

      ```
      nano ~/.local/share/applications/adt.desktop
      ```
   3. Paste this:

      *This can be done by right cliking inside your terminal window and then click `Paste`.*

      ```
      [Desktop Entry]
      Version=1.0
      Name=Android ADT
      Comment=Launch the Android ADT
      Exec=/home/username/ADT/eclipse/eclipse
      Icon=/home/username/ADT/eclipse/icon.xpm
      Terminal=false
      Type=Application
      Categories=Development;IDE;
      ```

      **Note:** Replace `username` by your username. You can get your username by executing `whoami` in a terminal.
   4. Save the file
   5. Execute the following command to make it executable:

      ```
      chmod +x ~/.local/share/applications/adt.desktop
      ```

---

If you've done everything right you've now succesfully installed the Android ADT. Open your Dash and search for `ADT`. Click on `Android ADT` to check if it's working!

Comment: Why do I need eclipse?

Comment: Nice one, added.

Comment: @Braiam Did you get answer of your question? because i also want to know why do we need eclipse

Comment: You don't need Eclipse, you just need an IDE (which Eclipse is). You can also use Android Studio if you like. It's the program you write your code in.

Answer (score 5):

You can also install `adt` and `android-sdk` from [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~linuxgndu/+archive/ubuntu/adt-raring).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxgndu/adt-raring
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install adt android-sdk
```

To complete the installation of `android-sdk` you need to:

```
sudo sh /opt/android-sdk/install-sdk
```

You can also install `android-studio`:

```
sudo apt-get install android-studio
```

---

Now check that the installation went as expected:

```
android-sdk-manager
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another alternative. Integrated Development Environments (IDEs) are supposed to make programming easier, one problem with them however is that it can be difficult to install the latest version of an IDE on a Linux system (Ubuntu) if they are not in the repos. **Android Studio** is one such IDE.

> Android Studio is the official IDE for Android application
>   development, based on IntelliJ IDEA. On top of the capabilities you
>   expect from IntelliJ, Android Studio offers: Flexible Gradle-based
>   build system Build variants and multiple apk file generation Code
>   templates to help you build common app features Rich layout editor
>   with support for drag and drop theme editing lint tools to catch
>   performance, usability, version compatibility, and other problems
>   ProGuard and app-signing capabilities Built-in support for Google
>   Cloud Platform, making it easy to integrate Google Cloud Messaging and
>   App Engine.

Extracted from: http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

Follow this procedure:

1. Firstly execute the following command.

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make`

2. Then update the repo.

> `sudo apt-get update`

3. Now install the software:

> `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make`

4. You will see all the package it will install, type ‘y’ to tell Ubuntu to proceed with the installation. Once you are done with it. Proceed with the following.

> `umake android`

Leave the installation path as the default value;

**Press enter again. 
You will have to agree to the license by typing ‘a’ then download starts.**

*Android Studio will then present you with a wizard, just keep hitting next and agree to the license. It will then proceed to download requirements for Android development, such as the latest Android SDK. Click on ‘Finish’ once the installation of required packages is complete.*

Comment: This should be the top voted answer.

Answer (score 0):

**CLI approach**

Tested on Ubuntu 15.10, Android 22.

One the device:

- enable developer mode and USB debugging: http://www.syncios.com/blog/enable-developer-optionsusb-debugging-mode-on-devices-with-android-4-2-jelly-bean/
- link device to computer with USB cable

Then:

```
sudo apt-get install ant gradle openjdk-7-jdk

cd

# Get device permissions.
# MANUAL find vendor ID on this table: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#VendorIds
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/5510745/895245
VENDOR_ID='054c'
UDEV_PATH='/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules'
echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR'"$VENDOR_ID"'=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"' | sudo tee "$UDEV_PATH"
sudo chmod a+r "$UDEV_PATH"
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart

wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
tar -xvf android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz

# MANUAL run the ./tools/android GUI and install the SDK versions you need 
# Better: just download EVERYTHING to save you annoyances later on.
# Yes, it takes a ton of space (50Gib+).
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line
# The automated command line should look something like:
#API=22
#N="$(android list sdk --all |& grep 'SDK Platform Android' | grep "API $API" | cut -d- -f1)"
#android update sdk -u -a -t $N

# Studio
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/1.5.1.0/android-studio-ide-141.2456560-linux.zip
unzip android-studio-ide-141.2456560-linux.zip
cd android-studio/bin
./studio.sh

# NDK
wget http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin
chmod a+x android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin
./android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.bin
mv android-ndk-r10e android-ndk
```

Add to your `~/.profile`: TODO: which of those are actually necessary?

```
export ANDROID_SDK="$HOME/android-sdk"
# Present on the default build.xml generated by "android create project [...] in Android 22.
export ANDROID_HOME="$ANDROID_SDK"
export ANDROID_NDK="$HOME/android-ndk"s
export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT="$ANDROID_NDK"
# Used by https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/3cd41e1f5280443665ca98463c7a76e80bf0b96c/native-codec
export ANDROID_NDK_HOME="$ANDROID_NDK"
export ANDROID_ABI='armeabi-v7a'
export ANDROID_JAVA_HOME="$JAVA_HOME"
export ANDROID_STUDIO="$HOME/android-studio/"
export PATH="$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:${ANDROID_STUDIO}/bin:${ANDROID_NDK}:${PATH}"
```

Logout and login. You may need:

```
sudo "$(which adb)" kill-server
sudo "$(which adb)" start-server
```

**Test the installation**

Get your hands on a [minimal project like this one](https://github.com/cirosantilli/android-cheat/tree/e117a827668c675cc8e59d23dee95247ff2a702a/min) or look under `$ANDROID_SDK/samples/`.

If it is an Ant project (contains a `build.xml` file) run:

```
ant debug
ant installd
```

If it is a Gradle project (contains a `gradlew` file) run:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
./gradlew installDebug
```

The app should be installed on your device.

Studio (ADT successor) can be launched with:

```
studio.sh
```

NDK samples can be found under `$ANDROID_NDK/samples` and you can build and install them with:

```
ndk-build
# Create build.xml, as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572304/how-to-build-the-android-sample-projectsusing-ant-build-xml-does-not-exist
android update project -p . -t android-22
ant clean
ant debug
ant installd
```

**State of official Debian packages**

There is currently no official Debian package.

But there is a Google Summer of Code 2015 project trying to solve that: https://www.google-melange.com/gsoc/project/details/google/gsoc2015/seamlik/5707702298738688

Comment: I'm not even sure why you logout and back in. you can just source the variables if you make the proper changes in your .bashrc file. for instance, `function cat_export_vars () { cat <<- _EOF_ (export directives) _EOF_ }` and then just use `cat_export_vars >> .bashrc` and then `. .bashrc` or `source .bashrc` which does the same thing. Better yet, this would be better as a script to set up a bare bones Android SDK.

Comment: @jargonjunkie logout / login: sure, that would work too. I just prefer to have some variables in `.profile` so they are visible to things launched from dashboard. Script: this is as close as I could get, note that there are some manual steps marked which I could not automate. https://www.google-melange.com/archive/gsoc/2015/orgs/debian/projects/seamlik.html is our current best hope.