# Android SDK Tool for Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation

I just want to ask what is the Android SDK app for ubuntu OS? I want to develop and practice making Android Apps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Installing the SDK means installing the files you need to make Android apps on Ubuntu. That is detailed in this post

[Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-on-ubuntu)

However, you probably want an IDE also, which is the graphical program in which you can write android apps.

Usually people have used Eclipse for this. Eclipse is an IDE that can be used for many languages, and there is a plugin (the ADT plugin) which allows you to create Android apps with Eclipse. To install, first install Eclipse from the Ubuntu Software Centre and then see this guide.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

There is another option, you can use Android Studio, which is based on another IDE called IntelliJ, however this is an early release which is not yet stable, and so using Eclipse is still recommended at this time.

For more information on Android Studio, see here;

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html