# ADT Installation Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: android, eclipse

It's been a while..

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my HP Sleekbook 14. It is working fine. Now i wanted to install ADT on it for android app development. I downloaded the package from the official android site. But i cannot open eclipse. The file 'eclipse' won't open.

I saw a tutorial for linux mint/ubuntu that said i could double click the file and eclipse will initiate. this one is not doing anything but asking me what software to open the file with.

The ADT i downloaded was adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030

one other thing, not that i expect it to have anything to do with this, i compiled in a 3.12.x kernel, it is the one running now...as opposed to the stock 3.11.x

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

;)

Comment: How did you `open` eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

First of all just confirm whether you are clicking on the correct 'eclipse' file because as you are getting a message asking on which application it should open because if it was an application it would run automatically and would not give such type of a message. Another distinct possiblity is that your files you downloaded may be corrupt and your eclipse file has got corrupted.

If you have the downloaded zip file just do a md5checksum and verify it with the md5 mentioned at the website. Note: Your downloaded version and the currently available version should be the same. To do that first open a terminal and go to the correct directory to check a downloaded file. Then type

```
md5sum <filename>
```

I have also installed through the adt bundle from the website and followed the instructions given on

[Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-on-ubuntu)

The Steps I followed are:

**Step 1:**

(Using software centre or command lines) Installed ia32-libs. If your Ubuntu is a 32-bit OS then install libgl1-mesa-dev

**Step 2:**

Check if you have a jdk I had openjdk-7 already installed. If not install openjdk-6-jdk or better, openjdk-7-jdk. You can also prefer oracle's jdk. But you need to check out the instructions for installing it as it is not available in software centre by default.

**Step 3**

Download ADT Bundle adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030.zip (For 32 bit it is adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030.zip) from developer.android.com and extracted it in my Home folder.

**Step 4**

Type in terminal

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Enter the following lines at the end or in the beginning of ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/eclipse
```

Here you have to replace **/home/username** by the **absolute paths** according to where you extracted ADT bundle download.

**Step 5**

Check that the unzipped ADT Bundle folder have the folders tools and platform-tools. These folders contain some important commands stored. Export them. Exporting them can be done as follows:

First execute

```
sudo gedit ~/.pam_environment
```

A file opens. Just add these lines to that file:

```
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/path/to/tools
PATH DEFAULT=${PATH}:/path/to/platform-tools
```

Here you have to replace **/path/to/tools** and **/path/to/platform-tools** by the **absolute paths** according to where you unzipped the SDK or the ADT bundle download. Now all the commands adb, android, emulator etc can be simply executed in the terminal without giving absolute paths. That is, you will not get a "command not found" error.