# Where to store Android SDK files

Tags: android, sdk

After reading [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-on-ubuntu) I was wondering where should I put my extracted Android SDK files (step 4)?

Answer (score 1):

`/opt` looks like the ideal place to put them in. I prefer to rename `adt-bundle-linux-x86....` to simply `android` so the sdk will be in `/opt/android/sdk`

> This directory is reserved for all the software and add-on packages
>   that are not part of the default installation. For example,
>   StarOffice, Kylix, Netscape Communicator and WordPerfect packages are
>   normally found here. To comply with the FSSTND, all third party
>   applications should be installed in this directory.
>   -- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/opt.html

Other choice is `/usr/local`

> These days, '/usr/local' is widely regarded as a good place in which
>   to keep self-compiled or third-party programs.
>   -- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/usr.html

Answer (score 0):

After extracting the zip file you can put it anywhere. When you open eclipse first time after ADT plugins installation, it asks you to browse the SDK folder.

You can also change it by going Window>>Preferences>>Android.(in eclipse).