# How to install adbbrowser?

Tags: installation

So I downloaded tar.gz file, extracted, and I got adbbroswer file. How can I install this file on ubuntu 13.10? ./configure does not work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken: there is no reason to use "configure". I downloaded the tar.gz, extracted and it has ONLY 1 file that is an executable. All I had to was click the executable:

[image]

There is a catch though for it to actually work:

> ADBbrowser is a GUI based file and application browser for Android devices. It will run on most 32 and 64 bit Linux systems and Windows 32 bit. Originally written for my Sony Ericsson X10i, But should work with all android phones.
>
> **Adbbrowser requires Android SDK to be installed!**

How you do this? See: [Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Gotcha, I was getting error "Executable not found: "adb", so I prolly need Android STK as you say :) thanks

Comment: Yes sir! That will fix the adb error (I got that one too ;-) )