# How to set up an environment to develop Android apps in Ubuntu that doesn't have internet Connectivity?

Tags: application-development, java, android

I have an Ubuntu laptop in which I need to develop Android apps. I know that all that software could be downloaded from the software center but the problem is that  I don't have internet connectivity to that PC. Instead, I have my friend's computer (running Windows) with Internet. So is there any way to download those packages manually from windows pc and copy them to my pc and install them?

Answer (score 0):

Not all steps in my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu) can be done without internet. However for the others this is a possible way out:

Do step 1 as in my answer.

The required packages in Steps 2 and 3 can be installed as follows:

1. Get those packages in .tar.gz form (you can google them) and download them on friend's PC and transfer to yours.
2. Follow the instructions in the accepted answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Step 4 in my answer can be done from your friend's windows computer. Thereafter transfer the downloaded zip in Step 4, to your machine via a USB device perhaps. Be sure to eliminate all errors, for instance dependencies, before returning your friend's PC.

Then do Steps 5 and 6 as in my answer.

Finally run `eclipse` in the folder in the `adt-bundle-linux/eclipse` folder.

Now you are ready to develop android apps.

This is a tedious process! I can't even appreciate the tedium of it, as I haven't been faced with installing stuff on a system without internet. I haven't tried this. Do try and let us know.