# Install apk in ubuntu

Tags: android

I am using android-x86 4.4 RC2 with linux ubuntu on an intel laptop. is there any way to install .apk in ubuntu since they are from linux. If there is a chance for it, please let me know.

Comment: Visit [Android SDK/ADT Bundle](http://askubuntu.com/q/318246/)