# How to configure Eclipse and Android SDK

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk, android-studio

I am very new to Ubuntu and I love to work on it because it gives me a nerdy feel.

Can anyone (without posting the link that is available here) share step-by-step instructions for how to configure Eclipse and Android SDK in Ubuntu 14.10?

The current position I am at is, I downloaded Android Studio. I then downloaded Java 7 JDK and configured it. I started Android Studio and it took me around three hours to download the packages, but afterwards it literally stops downloading further packages of "Google repository support" or something. So I decided to download Eclipse and work on it. Eclipse is not giving me any "Android application" submenu when I try to click New Project. I found out that in my ~/home folder I have an Android SDK folder. Many sites insisted that I should check it by running the command "android" in the terminal, but as expected it gave me an error that said: `command not found`.

Can anyone please help me to configure Eclipse (I have already downloaded it from the Ubuntu Software Center) along with Android SDK? I can still open the Android SDK Manager, but I haven't got a clue how to manage the Android virtual device. I didn't even find out how to configure it.

Comment: "But as expected it gave me error. " mind telling us, what the error was?

Comment: Could you provide the source where you follow the installation, and point where you got the error? Also, what is the error message?

Comment: Instead of swinging around wildly, you're going to have to follow the instructions in the link you don't want posted (presuming http://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu), step-by-step. Then you're going to have to tell us precisely which step is causing you problems, and show exactly what the error messages were, as well as what (if anything) you did to try to solve them. Otherwise, it's not possible to help you easily. You're going to want to level-up your nerdiness a bit before continuing.

Comment: First, **do not put the question title in uppercase**, skipping that, I think that you may improve your question putting the error that you said that happens.

Comment: @Braiam when I wrote "android" in the terminal, it gave me error "command not found"

Comment: thank you @AndrewT. for your response...my error lies is "command not found" while typing "android" in terminal and eclipse not giving me any "android application" sub menu when i try to click new project..i have the sdk folder in directory ~/home/

Comment: @JasonC i installed android studio..i tried to run the file ./studio.sh and it gave me the android studio application splash screen and moving ahead with the installation process it downloaded the android sdk version no.22..i also have it in  the folder in home directory..when i wrote "android" in the terminal.." no command found" error occurred...

Comment: I have Windows version, but I never know that there's `android` command inside the SDK. I know `adb` instead, so if you could point me where is the instruction to call that command, it'd be really helpful. Next, have you installed ADT plugins from Eclipse? After that, have you set the Android SDK path from the preference?

Comment: The "android"  command is in <installation dir>/android/tools/android, so either put that into your path, or just run it with the full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I would like to thank all the repliers here who has motivated me to move ahead and find the solution.. Thank you @karel for editing my question and turning it into  meaningful and sensible...

I have got the answer to configure it...i will explain all the step by step to configure eclipse and android sdk...

1) download android sdk from the google site : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

this will give u a folder named android-sdk after you extract it in any of your desired location...move on to the directory, /home/'usr'/Android/Sdk/tools and you will find the file named "android"....open your terminal (shortcut key is alt + ctrl + t) and paste the file in terminal and execute that file..(you can also do it going to terminal using 'cd' command) ....once you press enter you will have the sdk manager screen and download  and install your desired packages...

2) Now time to configure java...most of the time your eclipse supports java 7 jdk ...to configure java...as i mentioned earlier open up your terminal and type: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk` , or what you can do is you can open your software center and type java runtime on the search bar and you can install it from there too...

to check whether you have configured your java or not , open up your terminal and write this code: `java -version`  and you will get output as shown below:

3)its time to download eclipse now and configure it with Android sdk..
open your software center and type eclipse..

after you install it, open your eclipse software...
just recalling it (you have now, android-sdk, java, and eclipse...)

so after you got all your files..you need to download the adt(Android Development Tool) plugin...(and this is where I got stuck)

4) you have your eclipse software now opened, so go to `Help  -> Install New Software` and you will get a screen for inputs

you will see a ADD button, click on it, and now you will be asked whether local or location, so in location type this address: `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/`

you will get the names of all the plugins available and from this list, find out Android Development Tool listed and click next till you download and install it restart your eclipse

5) now its time to point your eclipse to android sdk.
after you restart your eclipse it will ask you to point your sdk

click browse and point your directory till /home/'usr'/Android/Sdk

6) there you are, it will ask for further inputs from you and you can follow the screen.

7) you can also see the virtual device option in eclipse if you have configured eclipse properly

enjoy developing!! :-)

let me know if there are any issues faced...or if there is any mistake with these steps.