# Failed to create SD card (& in AVD Folder)

Tags: android, eclipse, sd-card

Ubuntu version 14.04 LTS
My Machine Dell Inspiron 15 3000 Series

I am following the following article for installing Android Application Development Enviornment [Target Super Newbies; IDE Eclipse]

[Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu)

After completing 4th Step, I have not recieved the desired message. Following further... I have come upto Step 6. On following "Click your virtual device and then click Start....", I got message-

```
Error: Failed to create the SD card.
Error: Failed to create the sdcard in the AVD folder.
```

I executed the follwoing command as a remedial measure

```
apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
apt-get update
```

Now, I am getting following error in message box

```
Error: .../tools/mksdcard:error while loading shared libraries libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: Failed to create the SD card.
Error: Failed to create the sdcard in the AVD folder.
```

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into the same issue on my Ubuntu Trusty development machine. You can fix this error

```
error while loading shared libraries libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

by installing the corresponding 32bit library:

```
sudo apt-get install libgcc1:i386
```

I wish Google would stop requiring a 32 bit development platform, Android is the only reason I'm still carrying 32 bit libraries around.

Comment: Installing `lib32z1`, `lib32ncurses5`, and this library (`libgcc1:i1386`) fixed the bug for me on Ubuntu 16.04 when creating AVDs in IntelliJ Idea CE.

Comment: This solution perfectly worked on my ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

Duplicated here (but not recognized as duplicate by askubuntu.com):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878445/ubuntu-error-failed-to-create-the-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

This happens because some executable files in `sdk/tools` cannot be executed.
Go to your android studio and android sdk folders and make all directory and files executable by this command :

```
chmod +x -R *
```