# ERROR Installation Guide for Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu-sdk

According to the Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK/ADT Bundle on Ubuntu (already answered in 'askubuntu.com'), I tried to install 'android sdk' and everything was fine up to 4th option (up to '4. installing packages')
but after 4th option, from 5th (5. Editing ".bashrc") when I am proceeding, after running

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

in terminal a blank text is appearing.
Could not proceed further.

Comment: Which guide do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty `~/.bashrc` isn't a problem. That just means that nothing has been entered in the file. Fill in your configuration and continue with the installation.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu               ya this one I talked about!!

Comment: This guide is three years old. Use this: http://askubuntu.com/a/634085/367165

Comment: And as I said in the answer. An empty file isn't an error.

Comment: Thnx !!Ok I am going to try this one you gave .talking aboout "fill the configuration" , I mean, how can I  write all those written stuff in  text editor ?