# command not found error when installing android sdk

Tags: android, android-sdk

When installing `android sdk` on Ubuntu, I run the command `android sdk` as instructed on [Installing android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html) page but I get the `command not found` error.

See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: I think the correct command is `./android`. See [Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

It says "Open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory in the location where the Android SDK was installed, then execute android sdk." So you have to run it via shell. Use `sh android sdk`.