# Could not install platform-tools on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: android, ubuntu-sdk, sdk

I am planning to install Android SDK for my Ubuntu 15.10. I downloaded the latest version of SDK, uncompressed and put it in folder `/usr/local/android-sdk-linux` with folders add-ons, platforms, tools. But I could not find Platform-tools. For install same I try Android SDK Manager using command:

```
$ android
```

And try to install Platform-tools only like below:

[image]

I got the following error:

[image]

Advise me how I can install platform-tools to follow the post in
[How to add android sdk in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu) ..

Comment: Try installing with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

From IRC channel ubuntu I got solution. 
Thanks , and  .. According to them download the sdk
on /home (~) and do the following stuff make the problem finished

wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz

tar -xzf android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz

cd android-sdk-linux && ./tools/android

then my android sdk manager not shown any error...

Advise: Don't put sdk library in any other path than home of a user..

Thanks

Anes