# Java doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

I'm trying to install Android SDK, but it doesn't work.

I'm following this gist: https://gist.github.com/wenzhixin/43cf3ce909c24948c6e7

When I run the ./android command, I just get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.parseAvdInfo(AvdManager.java:1623)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.buildAvdList(AvdManager.java:1584)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.<init>(AvdManager.java:357)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.avd.AvdManager.getInstance(AvdManager.java:380)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.initSdk(UpdaterData.java:259)
    at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.UpdaterData.<init>(UpdaterData.java:127)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.SwtUpdaterData.<init>(SwtUpdaterData.java:61)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindowImpl2.java:104)
    at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.SdkUpdaterWindow.<init>(SdkUpdaterWindow.java:88)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showSdkManagerWindow(Main.java:408)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:391)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:151)
    at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:117)
```

My Java version:

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

My **~/.bash_profile**

[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

```
#[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
```

Any idea here?

Comment: i think problem with your path check this answer may help you i followed it before and work fine if you using android studio no need to install sdk it's provided with it in the installation file 

http://askubuntu.com/a/466245/464430

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend to install Oracle JDK 8.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html), the Java version required for Android SDK and Android Studio, is 1.8.  You need to install that one.

Comment: JDK 8 is only recommended i think this not the reason i was installing jdk 7 and work fine with me

Comment: No, it is not just recommended.  Read the instructions please.  It's a requirement.

Comment: may be for android studio 2.1 and as i mention before i tryed jdk with A.S and Eclipse , but i think he asks for sdk in general not android studio or eclipse

Comment: are you using ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: I updated to jdk 8, nothing changed, installed eclipse, nothing changed :(