# Error while accepting android liscences

Tags: android, android-sdk, googledart

Ok so i recently switched to ubuntu & i am having a hard time figuring out how to install everything and get Flutter development up and running. When i run flutter doctor i get:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#android-setup for
      more details.
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

When i run `flutter doctor --android-licenses`  i am getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 5 more
```

Running java --version:

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.8 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.8+10-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Installing flutter itself was easy. But then i followed multiple threads on how to install android-jdk in my machine which is where i think i messed up. Can someone guide me here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complete Installation Guide for Android SDK / ADT Bundle on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318246/complete-installation-guide-for-android-sdk-adt-bundle-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

- Open Android Studio
- Go to Tools > SDK Manager
- From the left choose, Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK
- Select SDK Tools from the top menu
- Check Android SDK Command-line tools and click apply.
- Run flutter doctor --android-licenses